# Change Ads automatically Drupal Ad module

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, ads

I am using the Ad module for Drupal 6 (http://drupal.org/project/ad). I am wondering if I can make the ad changes automatically every 60 seconds even if the user doesn't refresh the page.

Comment: You could certainly tweak it to work that way, but why? Isn't random better?

Comment: I want to keep it random. Now the ad changes only with the page refreshes, I want it to be changed randomly every 60 seconds (every 60 seconds a new add to be displayed)

Comment: Ah, that wasn't clear from your question. I've edited it to be more obvious what you'd like to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using the JavaScript method of ad insertion, you'll notice that the Ad module adds a script to the page which fetches some code from a file named serve.php in the Ad module directory (so it's bypassing Drupal bootstrapping and such). Use Firebug and check out the Net tab, JS subtab to take a peek at this. Assuming you have the coding chops, you could add a bit of JavaScript to your theme or a custom module which basically removes the current ad and re-calls serve.php just like the Ad module's script does.